# How to save multiple file fields to django using jquery and Ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, django

I am trying to save multiple file fields to server. Field fields are dynamic, we can upload as many file as we want using add button. I dont wanted to use form submit or dropzone. Can anyone please help me how to do it.

```
    <div class="row" id="point_of_interest">  
         <div class="col-lg-4 ">            
             <label>Point of Interest Name</label>
             <input type="text" name="point_of_interest_name"  class="form-control interest_name" >
             <label class="error"  style="color:red; display:none;"></label>
         </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 ">            
             <label>Upload Image</label>
             <input  type="file" accept="image/*" name="point_of_interest_image[]" class="poi_img form-control" placeholder="Upload image" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 ">            
            <div class="form-group">
                 <a class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg add_point_of_interest"  style="margin-top:33px;" ></a> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The above HTML is for dynamically adding form fields

```
    $('#point_of_interest').find('input[type=file]').each(function (index,val) {

        var city_image = $(this).prop(files)[0]; 
    console.log(city_image); 
    point_of_interest_image_list.push(city_image);

    });
```

The above jquery code is for collecting multiple objects

```
    @csrf_exempt
    def save_city_data(request):
    try:
       print '=====request========',request.POST
       print      '=====request========',request.FILES.getlist('point_of_interest_image_list')
```

Using above code I am getting list of all files

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery File Upload plugin